# Unexpected behaviour of isRelative()

Tags: c++, qt

I am using C++ Qt Library and i was filtering out the relative paths in my file, while debugging few strings other than relative paths are also considered as relative paths. I want to know the reason of this behavior of isRelative() or i am doing something incorrectly, following example is giving true.

```
QFileInfo fi("1");
qDebug() << fi.isRelative();
```

I am reading from a file, where only few entries are relative paths, so instead of returning true for only those entries, isRelative() is returning true for many values like: "1", "0.0", "NO", etc

Comment: `"1"` is not a number, it's a string that happens to contain a digit. It's no different from for example `"a"`.

Comment: Yeah i know that,  but it's definitely not  a relative path.

Comment: It *is* a relative path, since it's not absolute, like `"/1"` or `"/0.0"`. Any string that doesn't start with `"/"` is a relative path.

Comment: @molbdnilo yeah i was missing this point. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it not be relative you should specify the full path of where should it be searched (absolute path):

```
QFileInfo fi("/home/user/1");
qDebug() << fi.isRelative();
```

then it will not be relative.

In your case it is equivalent of:

```
QFileInfo fi("./1");
qDebug() << fi.isRelative();
```

[Reading: Absolute path vs relative path](http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/07/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix.html)

Comment: Actually i am reading from a file, where only few entries are relative paths, so instead of returning true for only those entries, isRelative is returning true for many values like: "1", "0.0", "NO"